# Generic types and polymorphism

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I have `BaseFragment`:

```
    public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment implements BaseMvpView {

        private BasePresenter presenter;

        protected void syncLifeCycle(BasePresenter presenter) {
            this.presenter = presenter;
            this.presenter.onCreate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            //noinspection unchecked
            presenter.onAttachView(this); //it works with a warning
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            presenter.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            presenter.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();
            presenter.onDetachView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            presenter.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            presenter.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

and many classes that extends it. For example `MainFragment`:

```
    public class MainFragment extends BaseFragment implements MainMvpView {

        MainPresenter<MainMvpView> presenter;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            syncLifeCycle(presenter);
            //presenter.onCreate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            //presenter.onAttachView(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            //presenter.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            //presenter.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();
            //presenter.onDetachView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            //presenter.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            //presenter.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
}
```

I want to avoid repeating the life cycle synchronization code of each fragment and presenter. Therefore I want to implement this process in the `BaseFragment`. In Java this line `presenter.onAttachView(this);` works but with a warning "Unchecked call `onAttachView(V)`"(I can live with this). But **Kotlin** does not allow me to do this at all

```
abstract class BaseFragmentKotlin : Fragment(), BaseMvpView {

    private var presenter: BasePresenter<*>? = null

    //...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        presenter?.onAttachView(this) //Does not work. "Out-projected type 'BasePresenter<*>?' prohibits the use of 'public abstract fun onAttachView(mvpView: V!): Unit defined in com.example.test.BasePresenter"
    }

//...
}
```

I really need advice on how to do this correctly.

**Edited:**

```
    public class BasePresenterImpl<V extends BaseMvpView> implements BasePresenter<V> {

        @Nullable
        public V mvpView;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAttachView(V mvpView) {
            this.mvpView = mvpView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDetachView() {
        mvpView = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        }
}
```

Here is the whole test code https://github.com/AlexNikolaTest/Test/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/mytest

Comment: Can you show `onAttachView` method from presenter?

Answer (score 5):

I think replacing the [star-projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) with `BaseMvpView` would help

```
abstract class BaseFragmentKotlin : Fragment(), BaseMvpView {

    private var presenter: BasePresenter<BaseMvpView>? = null

    //...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        presenter?.onAttachView(this)
    }

//...
}
```

The reason is that Kotlin distinguishes between `out` and `in` type parameters (also known as **covariant** and **contravariant** parameter types, respectively).

`in` type parameters state that the type parameter is to be *consumed* by the generic class, i.e. to be used as a parameter of a function, while `out` type parameters state that the generic class will *produce* a value of passed type 
parameter, i.e. to be used as a return type for some function.

the `onAttachView(V mvpView)` takes a contravariant type parameter which implies that it is not allowed for `V` to be of any type (it has to be of type `BaseMvpView` or a subclass) since you are *consuming* that value. That is, if `V` was totally unknown, we cannot safely read the parameter since `V` is expected to be an instance of `BaseMvpView`. However, if it were the case that `onAttachView` is *producing* ,i.e. returning, `V` object then star-projection would work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In that case i can not call method syncLifeCycle(presenter) from MainFragment (generic type MainMvpView can not be cast to BaseMvpView)

Answer (score 4):

You could try this, then you can have the unchecked warning in Kotlin as well ;-)

```
    if (presenter != null) {
        val p = presenter as BasePresenter<BaseMvpView>
        p.onAttachView(this)
    }
```

In your MainFragment

```
    syncLifeCycle(presenter as BasePresenter<BaseMvpView>)
```

Not sure if it works, just played around a bit in IntelliJ. But since generics are erased during compilation and casting a MainPresenter to BasePresenter should also be fine, there is a good chance it goes through.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can make it like this

```
interface IView

interface IPresenter {
    fun attachView(v: IView)
    fun detachView()
}

abstract class BasePresenter<V :IView> : IPresenter {
    protected var view: V? = null

    override fun attachView(v: IView) {
        this.view = v as V
    }

    override fun detachView() {
        view = null
    }
}

abstract class BaseFragment<P : IPresenter> : Fragment(), IView {
    protected lateinit var presenter: P

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        presenter.attachView(this)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        presenter.detachView()
    }
}

interface TestView : IView {
    fun doSomething()
}

interface TestPresenter : IPresenter {
    fun doSomething()
}

class TestPresenterImpl : BasePresenter<TestView>(), TestPresenter {
    override fun doSomething() {
    }
}

class TestFragment : BaseFragment<TestPresenter>(), TestView {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        presenter = TestPresenterImpl()
        presenter.doSomething()
    }

    override fun doSomething() {
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to attach view in base presenter

Comment: sorry @AlexNik , i think i skip some points of your question. so i just edited my answer. i removed some parts, only include `attatchView` and `detachView` since I think these 2 methods that you're interested in the most.

Comment: Hi @AlexNik just curious, is my updated answer help you? :D